# Mime Type issue for downloading csv file in firefox especially when tried to do it on server

Tags: c#, csv, httpresponse

I am trying to download data in the form of csv file by adding header amd mime types to response.
It works fine in all the browsers when I test them locally, but when I test them on server or from remote desktop, it is not working in firefox. what happens really there it is converting the data in to separate values but it is not taking the extension as csv, if I manually save the file with csv extension its fine, I couldn't figure out why its not working especially on server that to in firefox, here is my code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}",
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FileName) ? DFLT_CSVFILENAME : this.FileName)
);
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

after this I am building a stringBuilder with the data writing it to the response.

so, I am in an impression that setting header and mime types is an issue. But they all are looking fine, any work around plz...................

Answer (score 0):

content type for CSV is different for different browser, for IE it is "application/vnd.ms-excel"

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is, I am passing the file name with some spaces in between the words. Fire Fox will not accepts file names with spaces where as rest of the browsers will do. So I simply removed spaces in the file name then it worked.